# ¿Como puedo hacer que el valor elegido en un combo se pase al select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```js
function ComboAnio(){
 var meses = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getMonth();
  var y = d.getFullYear();
  var select = document.getElementById("selectFechaVigencia1");
  $("#selectFechaVigencia1").html("");
$("#selectFechaVigencia1").append('<option value="other">Seleccionar...</option>');
    for (var i = n; i >= n - 2; i--) {
            var opc = document.createElement("option");
            opc.text = y + "-" + meses[i];
            opc.value = i;
            select.add(opc)
            }
}
```

```html
<html DOCTYPE!>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<select id="selectFechaVigencia1" onclick="ComboAnio();">
    <option value="">seleccionar...</option>
</select>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Lo que quiero es que cualquier valor que seleccione del combo sea seleccionado.

Comment: Si quieres que al cambiar algo se ponga un valor en el select puedes hacerlo con JQuery

$("select"),html("<option value='Valor'>Text</option>");

Comment: ok, entiendo, pero eso seria en otra funcion?

Comment: Ponlo en una variable de texto que guarde los option "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>" y al final de tu for asignalo con el html() haber que resulta

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que armes el `select` al iniciar, a simple vista, los datos no son dinámicos, por lo que no veo mucho sentido de que se agreguen usando el evento `onclick`

```js
//Función que se ejecuta cuando termina de cargar la página
$(function() 
{
  var meses = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getMonth();
  var y = d.getFullYear();

  for (var i = n; i >= n - 2; i--) 
  {
    //Creo una opción
    var opcion = "<option value='" + i + "'>"+ y+"-"+meses[i] +"</option>";
    //La añado con append
    $('#Fecha').append(opcion);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Fecha">
  <option>Seleccione una opción</option>
</select>
```

Te recomiendo, que leas un poco la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/) de [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) porque estas incluyendo una librería muy pesada a tu proyecto, y prácticamente no la estas utilizando en el código que muestras.

Saludos

Comment: Claro que si, ya quedo solucionado muchas gracias, lo resolvi al instante.